# React Native Expo Keyboard is closing on pressing every time

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and I am using Expo.

I have a styled component for text input.

And I am using like this: `<TextBox isSecure isNumberOnly text={pinCode} setText={setPinCode} />`

If I write like that;

in TextBox.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const Div = styled.View`
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;
const Input = styled.TextInput`
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
`;
export default TextBox = (props) => (
  <Div>
    <Input
      secureTextEntry={props.isSecure}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChangeText={props.setText}
      keyboardType={props.isNumberOnly ? "number-pad" : "default"}
    >
      {props.text}
    </Input>
  </Div>
);
```

there is no problem.

But if I seperate like that;

in BorderedDiv.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export default BorderedDiv = (props) => {
  const Div = styled.View`
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
  `;
  return <Div>{props.children}</Div>;
};
```

in TextBox.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import BorderedDiv from "./BorderedDiv";

const Input = styled.TextInput`
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
`;
export default TextBox = (props) => (
  <BorderedDiv>
    <Input
      secureTextEntry={props.isSecure}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChangeText={props.setText}
      keyboardType={props.isNumberOnly ? "number-pad" : "default"}
    >
      {props.text}
    </Input>
  </BorderedDiv>
);
```

I loose keyboard in every stroke.

I searched but their situations did not suit with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several times I found a solution.
If I use like that:

in BorderedDiv.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const Div = styled.View`
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

export default BorderedDiv = (props) => {
  return <Div>{props.children}</Div>;
};
```

Keyboard doesn't dismiss on every tapping.

This is solution but I couldn't find why.